# What if what is possible follows from logic alone

Tags: logic, metaphysics, modal-logic

Suppose that every imaginative variation [I don't mean this in any technical sense] of what is physically possible is necessarily possible: because what I can imagine follows from logic alone.

already: □ (◊A → ◊A)
what i think i am asking is: ◊A → □◊A
and so: ◊A → □◊A → A

or have I misinterpreted that something follows from logic alone?

If not, and if you equate imaginability with metaphysical possibility, then anything about the physical world that is metaphysically possible is metaphysically actual. Which is, I confess, somewhat absurd.

Comment: You seem to be committing an error here:  □◊A → A. The necessarily possible is not necessarily the actual. Merely because the converse holds (A → □◊A → ◊A) does not mean the opposite holds.

Comment: i'm not sure that in my haste i'm not misreading it but:

"□◊A → A is provable from A →  □◊A"

Comment: really, you main it is possible to prove that the necessarily possible is actual because the actual is necessarily possible?

Comment: To put it another way, at a fork in the road, I go right. This makes it necessarily possible that I go right. Not sure why the converse follows: if it is necessarily possible to go right, I go right.

Comment: i don't know tbqh

"Dual to the theorem B, S5 has the theorem BO. which means that whatever is possibly necessary is simply so"

Comment: "Dual to the theorem B, S5 has the theorem BO. which means that whatever is possibly necessary is simply so." This would mean (1) <>[]A -> A; not(1*) []<>A -> A. The reason (1) is valid in S5 is that every world is accessible from every other world, so if it is true in world w that there is some world w* such that A is true in every world accessible from w* A is the case, then A must be the case in w also--as w is accessible from w*. That wouldn't be the case in sentence (1*) though. The order of the modal operators matters.

Comment: i dunno, i'm not disagreeing exactly but that's now how i read this:

For these reasons, there is a tendency to confuse (B): A→□◊A with □(A→◊A). But □(A→◊A) is not the same as (B), for □(A→◊A) is already a theorem of M, and (B) is not. One must take special care that our positive reaction to □(A→◊A) does not infect our evaluation of (B). One simple way to protect ourselves is to formulate B in an equivalent way using the axiom: ◊□A→A, where these ambiguities of scope do not arise.

Comment: (1) is valid in S5; (1*) is not. I agree that the line of the article you quoted is a bit hard to follow, but the author simply must have have meant (1), because the alternative is an obvious error. The fact that something is possible in every possible world just intuitively can't entail that that thing is actual. If it did mean that, then I think it'd also turn out that everything actual were necessary, and so the difference between contingent truth and necessary truth would collapse.

Answer (score 2):

I got a reply from a professor acquaintance: □◊A → A is simply illegitimate, comments were right.

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you want. SE specifically allows this. You could also integrate some content from the comments in it.